# Mapped enumeration yields no results

Tags: c#, automapper

I have run into a problem with my Automapper query not returning any results. Here is the code:

```
    public ViewResult List()
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get();
        var userListViewModel = new UserListViewModel();
        userListViewModel.Users = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<User>, IEnumerable<UserViewModel>>(users);

        return View(userListViewModel);
    }
```

`userListViewModel.Users` is not returning any results. I know that there are some users.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the AutoMapper code?

Comment: I don't have the source, only the automapper.dll

Comment: So users.Count() is > 0? Are you sure? Add `Debug.Assert(users.Any());`

Comment: 'userListViewModel.Users.Count()' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' int {System.NullReferenceException}

users.Count = 1

Comment: Then the problem is obviously related to the repository, not the code you present.

Comment: @user343159 ok thanks for looking that up but what is your conclusion from this information?

Comment: But the repository is returning an IEnumerable<User> which is entirely correct. What do you mean that the repository is at fault?

Comment: @usr The repository is working fine, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<User>, IEnumerable<UserViewModel>>();
```

where I should have had:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>();
```

Thanks for all of your comments, this issue is now resolved.

S